# sql script to export table's column data to another table's column

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

Let's say , I have two table with same schema but different data .
`Table_A` and `Table_B` .

```
Table_A
--------
ID(p_key)     Number(p_key)         Column3     Column4
-----------------------------------------------------
ID1                1                  AAA         BBB
ID1                2                  CCC         DDD
ID2                1                  EEE         FFF
ID2                2                  GGG         HHH
```

-

```
Table_B
--------
ID(p_key)     Number(p_key)         Column3     Column4
-----------------------------------------------------
ID1                1                  AAA_1       BBB_1
ID1                2                  CCC_1       DDD_1
ID2                1                  EEE_1       FFF_1
ID2                2                  GGG_1       HHH_1
```

I want to export(overwrite) `Table_B column3` data to `Table_A column3` , where `ID` and `Number` Columns data are equal .
After executing of script , Table_A's data should be ,

```
 Table_A
    --------
    ID(p_key)     Number(p_key)         Column3     Column4
    -----------------------------------------------------
    ID1                1                  AAA_1        BBB
    ID1                2                  CCC_1        DDD
    ID2                1                  EEE_1        FFF
    ID2                2                  GGG_1        HHH
```

How can I make this using sql script only ?
I use MS SQL-Server 2008 R2 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE TBLA
    SET TBLA.Column3=TBLB.Column3 --, TBLA.Column4=TBLB.Column4 if you want
FROM
    Table_A AS TBLA
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Table_B AS TBLB ON (TBLB.ID1 = TBLA.ID1 AND TBLB.ID2 = TBLA.ID2)
```

Please note that 'ID' columns (i.e. 'primary keys') must be unique (as pkeys are :).
But to be sure -as I don't know your exact table structure- before you execute the code above, create a `SELECT` statement with the join(s) and if the result set is correct, then add it to the `UPDATE`.